# Error with FastCGI install on CentOS 6.5

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fastcgi

I'm trying to setup FastCGI but keep getting the following error message:

```
Installing : mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-2.el6.rf.x86_64

Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-2.el6.rf.x86_64
semodule: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.
warning: %post(mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-2.el6.rf.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
 Verifying  : mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-2.el6.rf.x86_64
```

selinux is disable on my system and I'm assumming it wasn't installed in the first place as I can't locate the /etc/selinux/conf file.

Any thoughts on would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the output from 'sestatus'?

Comment: sestatus outputs disabled. Normally I'd expect systems with SELinux installed to have a config file where you can set the selinux directive as 'permissive', 'enabled' and 'disabled'. However, this is missing, so I'm assuming selinux was never installed but the manager has been setup. Would this be the case?